# How to fetch subscriptions from azure through powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Suppose I have different subscriptions in azure :

For eg:

```
A-uat
A-prod
B-uat
B-prod
C-uat
C-prod
```

Now I want to fetch only prod subscriptions from the azure portal one by one i.e.

```
A-prod 
B-prod
C-prod
```

To fetch the subscriptions, I am using (through powershell)

```
$subscription=Get-AzSubscription
```

Here I want to use a condition that lists only the prod subscriptions.

And to iterate through the subscriptions, I am using

```
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions)
{
$subscription. Name 
}
```

How should I list only the prod subscriptions and iterate through the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Where-Object` Cmdlet to filter out the subscription names that endswith `prod`.

```
$ProdSubscriptions = Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object { $_.Name.ToLower().EndsWith('prod') }
```

Comment: Can we use "-or" here?
Suppose I want to fetch more subscriptions which end with words other than 'prod', lets say production . How to do that? 
I am using -or here but that doesn't seem to work.
Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object { $_.Name.ToLower().EndsWith('prod' -or 'production')

Comment: You can use `-match` operator  if that the case `AzSubscription | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'prod|nonprod'`